# Where does the energy that release when bond is formed between two atoms come from?

Tags: physical-chemistry

When two atoms attracted to form bond, energy is released. But where does this energy comes from. Is this energy released when electrons goes to their ground state or somewhere else?

Comment: @Gert you are right about the possible duplicate - but it is conflating the issue by veering off into notions of kinetic energy; and note that doesn't have a particularly helpful answer at this point. This question is quite clearly asked and concise and I would like to leave it open to see if it attracts a better answer.

Comment: The energy comes from the quantum fields that span the entire universe and which are not in their ground states. Without going into any detail, special relativity answers this numerically with the mass-energy-momentum relation.

Comment: @CuriousOne : Oh please don't spare us! Please go into some detail about this!  I am dying to know the answer now.

Comment: @sammygerbil: I am too old to say that I would be willing to die for anything these days. Death will come on its own, no reason to invite it, certainly not for sake of a physics question that's a duplicate. :-)

Comment: I'm with Gert : this does seem to be an exact duplicate.  I agree with Floris that the answer in the duplicate is poor and it would be good to have a better one, but surely that answer belongs with the 1st qn, not here.

Comment: Hey every one Thank you for your kind reply. I have seen duplicate question but couldn't understand. I would be very glad if you tell me that in atom from where the energy is released during bond formation. Sorry if you don't understand my question. Actually English isn't my native language.